# How to convert 4 (signed int) to int?

Tags: python, byte

I am working with byte (receiving data from IOT devices)

There are a few terms that I dont understand.

For example:

If the document mentions the data size of 2 (signed int). Then for the next 2 value I should do:

```
((byteArray[0] << 8) + byteArray[1])
```

I actually dont get why we should do it. Anyway I need to know the resolve for :

- 4 signed int
- 2 (signed int MSB) + 1 (unsigned int, decimal part)

==========================================
For example:
If the list's first value is 0x01 -> the next 2 value is the data we want but it is 2 (signed int). My code handle for that is :

```
data = bytearray.fromhex(input)

#data size of 2 (signed int)
if data[0].to_bytes(1,'big') == b'\x01':  
    wanttedData = ((input[1] << 8) + input[2])

 #data size of 4 (signed int)
```

Comment: Could you clarify the question please. What exactly you need to do? you receive 4-bytes of signed int format and need to convert to int in python? Is this correct?

Comment: You say for the data size of 2 ... but byteArray[2] means that there are at least 3 items?

Comment: Can you add the bytes that you need to transform. In hexadecimal format for example

Comment: If you can actually get the data in the form of a `bytes` object, you can use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) library to unpack it into a variety of different data types.

Comment: question updated @NikolayZakirov

Comment: @ChauLoi do you have an example of what the bytes received from your IoT device are? And what integer values you are expecting that to represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) package is a good way to convert byte data into various types.  You need to know the endianness of the data.  From your example the data appears to be big endian.

For example, if the data is:

- byteArray[0] is an 8 bit signed integer
- byteArray[1:2] is a 16 bit signed integer
- byteArray[3:6] is a 32 bit unsigned integer

then you can decode the data using a format of `">bhI"` (the `>` indicates big-endian, and each letter corresponds to each data type), and you can extract the three values with:

```py
import struct

byte_string = b'\x02\x03\x05\x12\x34\x56\xff'
val0, val1, val2 = struct.Struct(">bhI").unpack_from(byte_string)
print(hex(val0), hex(val1), hex(val2))   # prints 0x2 0x305 0x123456ff
```

Comment: How do we define [0], [1:2] and [3:6]. Or the system automatically recognize the 16 bit signed or 32 bit unsigned

Comment: That was just an example.  The IoT device documentation should tell you the layout of the values among the bytes received.  We are using `struct` to extract the native values from the bytes by specifying the size and format or each value via the format string.